# Why rephrasing this combinatorics problem yields wrong result?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is asked here but I have a diffrent approach before reaching it [Correct approach-first answer in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427009/permutations-and-combinations-questions). It yields different result.

I'll restate the problem:

> Five separate awards are to be presented to select students from a
> class of 30. How many different outcomes are possible if:
>
> If a student can receive any number of awards

The correct answer is $30^5$. But if we rephrase the problem as: $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{30}= 5$ yields $\binom{34}{29}$, which is wrong.

Why applying the formula for "finding number of solutions for 30 unkowns adding up to 5" is wrong here? It seems reasonable enough?

Comment: Because the awards are separate. For example, if the awards have different colors, how can your 30 variables determine who gets the blue award, who gets the red award, etc?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it self-contained? I can't understand what your question is without following the link.

Comment: Also, there are two different questions in the link provided. It would help clarify your question if you included which question you are answering here. Even better would be to duplicate the text of the question here, to make this question more self-contained.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. If, for example, $x_1 = 2$. What exactly awards given to the first student. I under-count the case red-blue, blue-green, etc. :D